# Passing datetime as parameter in sybase stored procedure

Tags: sybase

i'd like to pass a datetime as parameter for a sybase stored procedure and use it for a query, but i always get the error

```
SQL Error: Syntax error during explicit conversion of VARCHAR value '2021-06-16 13:28:48.390' to a DATETIME field
```

My stored procedure is like:

```
create proc mystoredprocedure
       @mydate varchar(50)
select * from mytable where date =CONVERT(DATETIME, @mydate, 121)
```

Call:
`exec mystoredprocedure  '2021-06-16 13:28:48.390'`

Sybase docu for CONVERT code 121:

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss.sss (24 hour clock, ODBC canonical with milliseconds, 4-digit year)
```

Does anybody know why i get this error?

Thank you very much!

Andi

Comment: Why are you using a varchar as the proc parameter instead of a datetime? You can pass a number of different date formats in a string to a datetime parameter and it will handle them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Sybase ASE ...

I'm unable to reproduce the issue in my ASE 15.7 instance (ie, your code works for me).

Can you try explicitly telling ASE how to parse the string by using the `set dateformat` command?

From the manauls re: the [set command](https://help.sap.com/viewer/e0d4539d39c34f52ae9ef822c2060077/16.0.3.7/en-US/ab4114ddbc2b1014801ba0f7c01e4e10.html):

> set dateformat *format* – sets the order of the date
> parts (**m**onth/**d**ay/**y**ear) for entering datetime, smalldatetime, date
> or time data. Valid arguments are 'mdy', 'dmy', 'ymd', 'ydm', 'myd',
> and 'dym'. The us_english language default is 'mdy'.

In this case you'll want to try `set dateformat 'ymd'`.